# When should I start my own trucking company?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

When does it make sense to start your own trucking company? I'm level 3 and can get a bank loan for enough money to buy my own truck - will I make enough money by getting the loan and starting the company now, or should I wait until I can buy the truck with my earnings?

Comment: A question that has bothered me in SCS's trucking games since 18WoS:PttM

Answer (score 7):

Here is my analysis of pros and cons of owning your truck and company -

## Driving own truck

***Pros***

- Higher Payout per distance
- Free Roam and explore capability.

***Cons***

- Fuel and Damage Costs
- Rest meter does not refresh between deliveries.

So since you are at a very early level you would not be driving long trips. So rest factors do not affect you yet. But the Fuel and Damage costs can pile up early on since you are not earning that much for the distance you drive.
Start with collecting the first tier skills so you get bonus experience and payout for each type of delivery. Then invest in Long-distance and ADR skills after wards.

While you pursue these skills you should start getting 25-30 Eur/Km deliveries in Quick Missions. This is the stage when you can buy your own truck and establish your company, without getting drowned in installment and repair/fuel costs. If you dont have enough money yet go ahead a take the highest loan you can afford. This will allow you to expand your fleet early with more trucks.

Here are the pros and cons of a early and late company. They actually dont matter much except for the installment deductions.

### Early Loan for truck and Company

***Pros***

- Can Hire Drivers early and customize them with the right skills.

***Cons***

- Daily Installment deduction

### Late truck and Company with own money

Pros:

- No Installments. You keep all you earn.

Cons:

- Drivers you hire may be of higher level with less important skills on them.

I highly recommend that you reach at-least **Level 6** before buying your own truck with 1 skill point in High value, Urgent Delivery and Fragile Cargo and at least 2 points in Long-distance driving.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I waited and got my truck with earnings; sadly my maintenance costs and fuel kept deducting my wage (I crashed a lot).

Then, my game got corrupted, and I had to start again.  When I started again, I gained enough money to buy my first truck which I drove more carefully saved and saved.  Now, I have a great empire of 7 trucks and 2 large garages and I'm still hoping to expand.  I think you should wait and get your own truck, save your money and drive carefully.

P.S When you are working for someone, just jump to the service station when you are near enough to your destination to save time.